# How to find file on disk without use of directories

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm writing a C++ application that will watch to ensure certain files on disk exist.  I've explored ReadDirectoryChanges and FindFirstFile/FindNextFile functions as well as a simple polling solution.  My problem is that if the name of a parent directory changes or the file gets renamed I can't tell.  I don't want to watch the parent directories of the file for name changes.  Is there a way to tell if a file exists on disk without the use of directories?  I've been told this is possible using a memory address on the OS itself but I haven't found anything.  Perhaps I just don't know what I'm looking for? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "_I don't want to watch the parent directories of the file for name changes."_ Tough, probably. Why do the directories change name? Simply don't do that. If you have to, monitor it. Seems pretty simple...

Comment: Using direct address on the OS itself? Hmm... Are you still using DOS?

Comment: It's not difficult to watch for changes in the naming, just tedious if the file is nested in very many directories.  I was hoping there was a way to check file existence without utilzing the directories at all.  Perhaps that's wishful thinking though.

Comment: I ran into the same case when I was trying to get filenames and directories with a breadcrumb style. I couldn't find any other way than the ways you have tried. Have you read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @YePhIcK - I'm not sure? I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 if that tells you anything?

Comment: @Evan - I have read that article. Thank you though.  I believe using the direct address on the OS as YePhick mentioned is what I was thinking of and what I was told.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open a known file, either identified by file ID or by GUID, using the [OpenFileById() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365432(v=vs.85).aspx).

See also ["If you want to use GUIDs to identify your files, then nobody's stopping you"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/28/10134679.aspx) on Raymond Chen's blog.

Comment: Also looks promising! I'll explore this further.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get to this.  Worked just as I had hoped.  Thank you.

Comment: I love OpenFileByID(), but keep in mind that file/folder renames and moves don't impact the file ID (the file reference number) or any guid you've attached to the file...so the file might still exist..but not be where you originally put it.  Also - it is possible for the file to get deleted, and then somewhat later - to be recreated.  File has new File ID and any guid you assigned is gone!

Comment: @Clay: generally the point of opening a file by ID is precisely so you can still find it even if it is moved.  If you want to check the current location of the file you can use GetFinalPathNameByHandle().  If the file is deleted and then recreated it isn't the same file any more from the operating system's perspective, but yes, it is necessary to be aware of whether or not the application(s) expected to manipulate the file are likely to do that - good point.

Answer (score 2):

[Change Journals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798.aspx) are probably what you are looking for:

> An automatic backup application is one example of **a program that must check for changes to the state of a volume to perform its task**. The brute force method of checking for changes in directories or files is to scan the entire volume. However, this is often not an acceptable approach because of the decrease in system performance it would cause. Another method is for the application to register a directory notification (by calling the FindFirstChangeNotification or ReadDirectoryChangesW functions) for the directories to be backed up. This is more efficient than the first method, however, it requires that an application be running at all times. Also, if a large number of directories and files must be backed up, the amount of processing and memory overhead for such an application might also cause the operating system's performance to decrease.
>
> To avoid these disadvantages, the NTFS file system maintains an update sequence number (USN) change journal. **When any change is made to a file or directory in a volume, the USN change journal for that volume is updated with a description of the change and the name of the file or directory.**

So, you can monitor a volume's Change Journal records for file creations, filename changes, file moves, file writes, etc, and you will know the exact files they apply to.